# Lazy loading showcase primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, lazy-loading

I want to use lazy loading in a datatable in my app. I browsed through the example on the Primefaces showcase website: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml. However I fail to understand how this is an example of lazy loading.

The first time the application loads the page, he still does get 200 cars. I would expect (as I wanted to implement lazy loading this way in my app as well) that the first time the app loads this page, he only loads as many entries as there are rows on the first page, then when the user clicks on the second page the next x entries get loaded and so on.

As I have a potentially huge datatable (more than a million records) I obviously do not want to load a million records, and let the user wait 5 minutes, if he only needs something from the first 20 records.

EDIT: Even worse, when I use a spring backing bean which is viewscoped I noticed he loads all records every time the user switches to another page. I would even benefit from using a datatable without lazy loading this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is just to show how it works. It's up to yourself to implement the method:

`public List<?> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)`

This one is part of the `LazyDataModel` class which you have to extend.

If you implement this method in a way that it will only get the records required for the page (that is, all records from `first` to `first+pageSize`) then you will have proper lazy loading. The showcase just has no database implementation example available.

Comment: But how is the example on the showcase a lazily loaded datatable? Why didn't they show an example which is actualy lazy loading? service.createCars(200) still created 200 cars instead of 20

Comment: It's showing how the frontend can work properly with lazy loading and pagination. Since they need some kind of datasource to show the pagination they need to create a pool of cars. Maybe this is not the best example from their side. The example might have been a little better if they e.g. put all the cars in an application scoped bean (which acts like the database) and then query on that bean instead of initializing the list of cars in the viewscoped bean.